# Showing more than one flashdata Codeigniter view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to show 2 flashdata using bootstrap alert. One for success, and one failed.

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')) : ?>
     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center">
        <?=$this->session->flashdata('msg')?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried to make 2 of it, the result, always showed FAILED while inserting submit data was succeed.

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg')) : ?>
     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center">
        <?=$this->session->flashdata('msg')?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')) : ?>
     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center">
        <?=$this->session->flashdata('error')?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: This is my controller, sorry if it's a bit crazy LOL

```
public function dosignup(){

    if ($this->daftar_model->dftrlogin() == TRUE){
        $//this->daftar_model->dftrlogin();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','REGISTERED');
         redirect(base_url('signup'));}
    else{
            // Form validation failed, set error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','FAILED');
            redirect(base_url('signup'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: mention here your controller code also.

Comment: @jyotimishra there..

Comment: what is $this->daftar_model->dftrlogin() returning? is it bool true or string true?

Comment: it's for inserting data into mysql.. like I said, I do it in crazy way

Answer (score 0):

since you are using if else expect 
one result of  flash data
else
you will make it double if

for example

```
if(strlen('john') == 4){
   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','REGISTERED');
}

if(strlen('johns') == 5){
   $this->session->set_flashdata('error','REGISTERED');
}

   redirect(base_url('signup'));
```

this is just a sample this one will return two flash data
one is msg and error